# Impact of ending contract with know-ins-and-outs lead developer of a project

Tags: freelancing, knowledge-transfer, team-leader

I have a long time running project. Its been running for about 6 months. The project is very big. The lead developer/team leader  designed the project and the whole project is in his brain. He knows all ins and outs. I also know almost everything. But I am not confident like him.

Problem is recently he is charging quite high for simple bug fix and small change request. I am worried if I end the contract what will be the future of the project. I had 2-3 public demos. I must launch soon. The project is still in development alpha.

1. What happens to the project if I end the contract?
2. Are the high charges is because he knows I can not end the contract now?

Comment: 1. What is the contract? 2. We cannot tell you

Comment: @JanDoggen 1. Contract is I create some requirement and he full fills.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What actions to take when people leave the team?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/what-actions-to-take-when-people-leave-the-team), or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162573/project-frozen-what-should-i-leave-to-the-people-after-me, or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/13470/how-do-programmers-quit-a-job

Comment: If you have a good relationship with him, try to have a non-confrontational chat where you say you are finding it hard to fund the recent charges. See what he says. It'll be helpful if you can look forward to some future days of profit when you might be able to ask him to do large amounts of work. But do not lie - only say that if there is some prospect it might happen. If you don't have a good relationship, it's harder.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What happens to the project if I end the contract?

You will have more work, you will gain more confidence, the project will be yours.

> 1. Are the high charges is because he knows I can not end the contract now?

This is a possibility. If you want a confirmation, suggest him that you can't afford such high charges and therefore that you will do the work yourself. He may end the contract or lower his charges.

Comment: He may have enough of the project (being bored with it), and increase the charges so that the money overcomes his boredom.